# Time Complexity of Text Justification with Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, dynamic-programming

I've been working on a [dynamic programming problem involving the justification of text](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-18-word-wrap/). I believe that I have found a working solution, but I am confused regarding this algorithm's runtime.

The research I have done thus far has described dynamic programming solutions to this problem as **O(N^2)** with **N** as the length of the text which is being justified. To me, this feels incorrect: I can see that O(N) calls must be made because there are N suffixes to check, however, for any given prefix we will never consider placing the newline (or 'split_point') beyond the maximum line length **L**. Therefore, for any given piece of text, there are at most **L** positions to place the split point (this assumes the worst case: that each word is exactly one character long). Because of this realization, isn't this algorithm more accurately described as O(LN)?

```
@memoize
def justify(text, line_length):

    # If the text is less than the line length, do not split
    if len(' '.join(text)) < line_length:
        return [], math.pow(line_length - len(' '.join(text)), 3)

    best_cost, best_splits = sys.maxsize, []

    # Iterate over text and consider putting split between each word
    for split_point in range(1, len(text)):
        length = len(' '.join(text[:split_point]))

        # This split exceeded maximum line length: all future split points unacceptable
        if length > line_length:
            break

        # Recursively compute the best split points of text after this point
        future_splits, future_cost = justify(text[split_point:], line_length)
        cost = math.pow(line_length - length, 3) + future_cost

        if cost < best_cost:
            best_cost = cost
            best_splits = [split_point] + [split_point + n for n in future_splits]

    return best_splits, best_cost
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
Ethan

Comment: The canonical DP algorithm here instead checks the penalty (or cost) of all start and end positions.

ie) cost[i][j] = penaltyForWordsOnLineBetween(i,j)

For all valid positions i,j

which is N^2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your implementation is going to be far, far from the theoretical efficiency that you want.  You are memoizing a string of length `N` in your call,  which means that looking for a cached copy of your data is potentially `O(N)`.  Now start making multiple cached calls and you've blown your complexity budget.

This is fixable by moving the text outside of the function call and just passing around the index of the starting position and the length `L`.  You are also doing a join inside of your loop that is a `O(L)` operation.  With some care you can make that a `O(1)` operation instead.

With that done, you would be doing `O(N*L)` operations.  For exactly the reasons you thought.

Comment: Good idea on the memoization optimization